Necessity of path-ordering in Wilson lines for non-Abelian gauge theories
In section 25.2.2  of Schwartz's QFT book, the author claims that for the non-Abelian case, the path-ordering operator is necessary to ensure the correct transformation properties of Wilson lines.
\begin{equation}
W_P(x, y) = P \left\{\exp\left( ig \int_{x}^{y} A_\mu^a(z) T^a \, dz^\mu \right) \right\}
\end{equation}
$$
W_P(x, y) \rightarrow e^{i \alpha_a(x) T^a} W_P(x, y) e^{-i \alpha_a(y) T^a}
$$
I’m struggling to demonstrate this. The author performs a Taylor expansion of the exponential
$$
W_P(x, y) = 1 + i g  \int_0^1 \frac{d z^\mu(\lambda)}{d\lambda} \, A_\mu^a(z(\lambda)) T^a \, d\lambda - \frac{1}{2} g^2 \int_0^1 d\lambda \, \int_0^1 d\tau \, \frac{d z^\mu(\lambda)}{d\lambda} \frac{d z^\nu(\tau)}{d\tau} A^a_\mu(z(\lambda)) A^b_\nu(z(\tau)) \left[ T^a T^b \, \theta(\lambda - \tau) +  T^b T^a \, \theta(\tau - \lambda) \right] + \cdots
$$
then claims θ-functions are necessary.
Any help is very appreciated.

Do you understand why the Dyson series for the time-evolution of a time-dependent Hamiltonian has time-ordering? This is essentially the same concept - just the "evolution" here is the parallel transport along the line generated by $A(z)$ instead of time evolution generated by some $H(t)$.
